# In python, selenium. Is there a way to see the amount of data taken to load a site?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, browser

I'm often using selenium and I would like to know from browser.Firefox() to browser.close(), how much data i used to load everything. Is this something selenium can measure?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access to requests and response data to do what you want.

To do it, you could set a proxy to log the requests and the response. [browsermob-proxy](https://browsermob-proxy-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is widely used for this tasks, especially for selenium.

Or alternatively, use [selenium-wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire) instead of selenium.

If you're interested and want some valid code example, you can email me. You find my address in my profile.

Regards